# I can't add the bot in my MSTeam application

Tags: botframework, chatbot, microsoft-teams

I'm using visual studio 2019 for creating a bot application and I have run it successfully that I added the Bot in Microsoft Team using [botframework.com](https://botframework.com) and I was downloaded the MSTeam application and installed but it doesn't show my Bot app in msTeam Application

MSTeam channel creation in botframework:
[image: pic of MSTeam channel]

MSTeam Application:
[image: pic of MSTeam app]

I have only 3 option such as activity, chats, calendar on the left panel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Need to get access from admin account for app store to Microsoft teams.
In Office 365 admin center, in settings for Microsoft Teams. Turn on the option "Allow external apps in Microsoft Teams". So that you can view app studio in your Teams.

Comment: ok but i don't know how to access this account

Comment: there is no option in Teams that I have checked in the office 365

Comment: please coordinate with your administrator for access. Seem you have guest access.

Answer (score 0):

https://teams.live.com/ (personal/simple/only rallies and meetings)

https://teams.microsoft.com/ (classic)

There are two versions of the application, personal and classic. Personal even for 2023 does not support third-party applications and the use of bots. It was with grief that I managed to connect the bot to the personal version, but the chat with him was blocked. We hope the developers will bring this version to the level of the classic. (You have a personal version in the screenshot).

Answer (score -1):

I don't have experience with botframework.com, but I'm assuming the behavior is going to be the same as when I manage bots through Azure. Turning on the channel itself isn't sufficient to add the bot to teams. There are (at least) two methods you can use to add the bot:

1. Copy the bot's Microsoft App Id and enter it into the To: field of a Teams chat. The bot should come up and you should be able to chat with it if the channel was set up correctly. **It is not a good idea to share this app ID with others. I'd use this only for your own personal testing.**
2. Create a Teams app manifest and load the app into Teams. There are a number of ways to create a manifest, but the easiest is to use the "App Studio" app from the Teams app store.

If you go the Teams app route, you can either sideload the app (which again, Teams App Studio makes that process easy but you can also *Upload a custom app* from the app store tab) or you can submit to your company app store. If you do not have a company app store, you'll need to sideload until you are ready to submit to the Microsoft App Store (if that is your end goal).

Comment: i don't have a app store option in MS Team application. u see second picture ?

Comment: Hi @MuthuMani Could you please confirm in which tenant(Org or personal) you are using Teams app and need to add permission from admin account for getting app store.

Comment: i have used this account Type **Accounts in any organizational directory (Any Azure AD directory - Multitenant) and personal Microsoft accounts (e.g. Skype, Xbox)**